# BottomSheetBehavior not draggable if i do not set peekHeight

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, bottom-sheet

In my app I have a bottom sheet and a button that makes it collapse/expand.

If `peekHeight` is not set the bottom sheet is not draggable and does not collapse, it is always visible.

Here is the code:

```
        View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet1);
        mBottomSheetBehavior1 = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

        mBottomSheetBehavior1.setPeekHeight(0); //IF I OMIT THIS, IT DOES NOT WORK

        mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mBottomSheetBehavior1.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    mBottomSheetBehavior1.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                    mButton1.setText("Collapse 1");
                }
                else {
                    mBottomSheetBehavior1.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    mButton1.setText("Expand 1");
                }
            }
        });
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `BottomSheetBehavior` is **not** [hideable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html#attr_android.support.design:behavior_hideable).

You have to explicitly tell, that you want that behavior to be hideable:

```
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
```